# Error in pointer declaration of structure variable

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why am I getting segmentation fault with this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    int                 val;
} DEVICE;

main()
{
DEVICE  *dev_ptr;
dev_ptr->val = 21;
printf(" %d   ",dev_ptr->val);
}
```

I know the correct way of assigning the values. For that we need to add these lines

```
DEVICE simple;
dev_ptr = &simple;
simple.val = 21;
```

but I want to know what is wrong with previous code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code, `dev_ptr` is used uninitialized. Using uninitialized memory leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), with a possible side effect of a segmentation fault.

You need to allocate memory [what you're doing in second snippet] to the variable before using [dereferencing] it.

You've got the compile-time memory allocation and using that address for `dev_ptr` absolutely correct in your second code snippet. Now, see the below code for dynamic allocation.

Try something like

```
int main()    // use proper signature
{
DEVICE  *dev_ptr = malloc(sizeof(DEVICE));   // allocate memory

  if (dev_ptr)                                 //check for malloc success
  {
    dev_ptr->val = 21;
    printf(" %d   ",dev_ptr->val);
  }

free(dev_ptr);                                 //make valgrind happy, prevent memory leak
return 0;                                      // have a return statement
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you assign to `val`, the `dev_ptr` is uninitialized, you never set it to point at somewhere valid.

So you're (probably) writing to a "random" location in memory, which (absolutely) gives undefined behavior.

The fix should be something like:

```
DEVICE my_device;
DEVICE *dev_ptr = &my_device;
dev_ptr->val = 21;
printf("my_device.val=%d\n", my_device.val);
```

The above will print `21`.